# Pricing when using google map inside in-app browser

Tags: dictionary

I want to know the price when i use google map inside in app browser. Is there any pricing policy in this case? Or No additional price

I want to make google map to use inside in-app browser. Please give me quick solution.

Comment: There is no charge for Google Maps.  What makes you think there is?.